# Can a replica have row-based replication enabled if the primary has only statement based replication?

Tags: mysql, database, database-replication

I have been searching in vain to find something I recalled which said a replica database cannot have row-based logging enabled if the primary database doesn't have it enabled. Is this true? How does it work with mixed logging format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true. A replica may log events in row-based format, whether the events it receives from an upstream source are in row-based or statement-based format.

The problem case is the opposite of what you were searching for. If the original source logs in row-based format, then its replica can only log events in row-based format.

Mixed logging format is just statement-based by default, but row-based for  statements that source determines are non-deterministic. This is also a problem if you rely on statement-based logs on the replica, because sometimes they will be forced to be row-based.

I'm not sure why you're asking. Row-based logs are usually preferred to statement-based logs. For example, CDC tools require row-based logs.